# How to delete old rows from sqlite database on android?

Tags: android, datetime, sqlite

I have a parameter, where user can choose for which period of time data should be stored.
I read it in `days` variable. Date and time, when record was added to the database is stored in `KEY_DATE_ADDED`, it is created like:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  // sql date format
Date date = new Date();
initialValues.put(KEY_DATE_ADDED, dateFormat.format(date));
```

Then I do the following:

```
mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, 
           "date(now) > date(" + KEY_DATE_ADDED + ",+" + days + " days)",
           null);
```

and it doesn't work. Actual query (where part) looks like:

> WHERE date(now) > date(date_added,+10
>   days)

What is incorrect here? Looks like instead of `date_added` something else should be here.
I wanted to use [SQL data formatting](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to avoid re-formatting dates several times.

Is there any GUI for Android database to test SQL queries on the actual data?

Comment: ok, I should use `date('now') > date('date_added','+10 days')` - it works now. So, the open question is only about GUI.

Comment: you can use `adb pull /data/data/<namespace>/databases/<dbName>` to pull the db from the emulator. I use the Firefox add-on "SQLite Manager" to view or edit the database.

Comment: What I did to test queries and whatnot was play around with SQLiteBrowser: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/ It's pretty easy to work with, you just have to extract your Database from your device (emulator or actual phone) and then go wild. I'm not really at my work station right now, but extracting the DB is fairly simple through the interface. Emulator/device instances store SQLite3 databases in the folder /data/data/<package_name>/databases/. See this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292818/inspecting-android-sql-database-from-eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I should use `date('now') > date('date_added','+10 days')`

Comment: I guess it should be `date('now') > date(date_added,'+10 days')`

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that may also need to periodically use the VACUUM command to actually reduce the size of the database.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html