# Access phone device Database by phone users

Tags: android, database, deployment, permissions

I know we can access device database thru abd tool with rooted privilege. My questions are 1. how the installed app access the database if I installed the app thru email (not thru the android market) 2. if this app is distributed by the Android market, is the db still can be installed at the /data/data/packagename/databases?

This is how I did on the question 1.

I used self-certificate-key-store to sign the app, email it to my acct., and then installed it on my phone. When I launched the app, my app still can't find the App's database which is supposed to be copied from asset to /data/data/packagename/databases.
This part was working fine in the eclipse emulator.  Do I need to configure something on my phone, in order to write the database to the /data/data/... directory? This really drives me crazy...

Question 2:
If the apps distributed by the android market, can that app is able to copy the database from the asset folder  to /data/data/.. Moreover, does phone users has previlege to change data to that database at /data/data/.. My apps are supposed to ask  phone users to save their data to the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) can help you with initializing your database from assets.

W.r.t. Q2: It does not matter which way your app came to the phone. As long as its package name and its signature public key are the same the app is treated exactly the same.

And, yes, your app can of course read and/or write to its own database(s). The common "non-root" user has *no* direct access to it but only via *your* app.

Comment: Hanno,

Thanks for your reply.
I have no problem doing everything at the emulator including copied the exsiting database from the "assets" folder to the system database /data/dat/...
The thing bothers me is why the database in the app deployed thru the email staill can't be accessed by the phone users?


Is the problem caused by the certificate signature? 
I did follow the instruction to sign it. Is any way to debug this?
Your answer is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to install your app on a real device via USB using the SDK (adb)? Via USB you can also use *adb shell* and then have a look what actually *is* written to your /data/data/... directory - or just use [DDMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292818/inspecting-android-sql-database-from-eclipse).