# Retrieve Database from Android Hybrid App

Tags: android, sqlite, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed a hybrid app using IBM work light. I would like to view the database created in the app while debugging. I am not able to locate it in the android application. Is it not created inside /data/data/packagename/database like the usual android app? If not where can i retrieve it from?

Comment: on not rooted devices you cant see the files in `/data/data/mypackage` from outside of mypackage

Comment: I am using a non-rooted device only. But I could retrieve DBs from native android apps using the adb back up command. But when I use the same with the hybrid app, I don't see the database folder at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to debug your application in a physical device, and this device is **not** rooted, you will not be able to inspect the filesystem.

The alternative is to:

1. Root your device, after which you will be able to look into the file system. You can then likely follow this: [Inspecting android sql database from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292818/inspecting-android-sql-database-from-eclipse) (or any other method of inspecting the file system)
2. Use the Android Emulator, which is rooted by default.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Could you please tell me the exact location where the DB is stored in hybrid android apps?

Comment: A hybrid application is not different from a native application in this respect. Clarify what "database" you are referring to.

Comment: I am referring to the (SQLite)database created by my app. I am not accessing any remote DB server. All data relevant to the app are stored as tables locally.Hope I answered your question

Comment: Created how? What code did you invoke? anyway, the answer is the same. You need to root the device. You can then inspect the filesystem as Selvin mentioned in the comments above and to do so you can use any method available, such as in my answer or otherwise. First thing first - root the device.